# React Native Component Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two classes, ActivityList, and ActivityDetail. ActivityList queries for some data and then calls ActivityDetail with the information it receives. I console logged the information and checked to see if it is coming in the desired form. It is. However, for some reason ActivityDetal is not rendering into ActivityList.

**ActivityList.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ActivityDetail from './ActivityDetail';
import { getCurrentUser } from '../../models/User';

class ActivityList extends Component {
  getActivityList() {
    getCurrentUser()
    .then(currentUser => currentUser.teacherList.map(batch => firebase.database().ref(`/batches/${batch}`)
    .once('value')
    .then(Class => firebase.database().ref(`/users/teachers/${Class.val().Teacher}`)
    .once('value')
    .then(teacher => this.renderActivityList(teacher.val())))));
  }

  renderActivityList(teacher) {
    console.log(teacher);
    return <ActivityDetail key={teacher.Name} person={teacher} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
         {this.getActivityList()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export { ActivityList };
```

**ActivityDetail.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardSection } from './';


const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ActivityDetail = ({ person }) => {
  console.log('working');
  return (
    <Card style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <CardSection>
        <Image style={styles.headerStyle} source={{ uri: person.Header }} />
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <Image style={styles.profileStyle} source={{ uri: person.Profile }} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ width: 0.93 * width, height: 0.09 * width }} />
      </CardSection>
      <CardSection>
        <View style={styles.textContainerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.nameStyle}>{person.Name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.classStyle}>{person.Subject}</Text>
        </View>
      </CardSection>
    </Card>
  );
};

const styles = {
  profileStyle: {
    height: 0.13 * width,
    width: 0.13 * width,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  containerStyle: {
    width: 0.18 * width,
    height: 0.18 * width,
    borderRadius: (0.18 * width) / 2,
    backgroundColor: '#d5d5d5',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: 65,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  nameStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#000',
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
  headerStyle: {
    width: 0.93 * width,
    height: 0.25 * width,
    borderRadius: 4,
    flex: 2,
  },
  textContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  classStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#aaa',
  },
};

export default ActivityDetail;
```

Comment: you dont have to render the ActivityDetail class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in your `ActivityList` component's render function, you are rendering the result of `this.getActivityList`, which is always gonna be undefined.

You should instead trigger the data fetch in `componentWillMount` and use setState to set the data to the component state for rendering.

e.g.

```
class ActivityList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { teacher: {} };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getActivityList();
  }

  getActivityList() {
    ... // get Data
    this.setState({ teacher : data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <ActivityDetail key={this.state.teacher.Name} person={this.state.teacher} />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```